# Two different recurrence relations, same solution

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

Say, I want to solve two recurrence relations in 2D given by
$$\begin{cases}\alpha_{i,j}=\frac{1}{4}\left(\alpha_{i+1,j}+\alpha_{i-1,j}+\alpha_{i,j+1}+\alpha_{i,j-1} \right)\\\alpha_{i,j}=\frac{1}{4}\left(  \alpha_{i+1,j+1} + \alpha_{i-1,j+1} + \alpha_{i-1,j-1} +\alpha_{i+1,j-1} \right)\end{cases}$$
where $\alpha_{i,j}$ is the solution to both equations simultaneously for the same choice of boundary values $\alpha_{i,j}^B$ for each equation. Now I'm wonderng, if there can exist such solutions. My intuition is that there shouldn't, especially as the equations are not linear superpositions of each other. I'm not sure if my question is already ruled out by uniqueness of the solution.

Comment: Well, if $i$ and $j$ did not have boundaries, then I would expect all constants ($\alpha_{i, j} = c$) to be solutions, along with vertically constant solutions $\alpha_{i, j} = a_i$ for adequate $a_i$

Comment: Without boundaries I know that there exist solutions of the form $\alpha_{i,j}=a^ib^j$ which solve both of them, but this is only true for an infinite plane

Comment: Is the question then whether there are boundary conditions and solutions which are not restrictions of solutions to the infinite problem? Certainly, any region of a solution for the infinite plane can be viewed as a solution to a bounded problem

Comment: this is actually an interesting idea ... I never looked at this from that perspective. So my question is originally regarding any boundary condition, but maybe this already works

Comment: @S.Klumpers so while using the infinite plane and then truncating it works, I'm now interested if there exist other boundary conditions not generated by this. In that sense, something regarding the existence of solutions to both equations simultaneously for given boundary conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a mesh of $n \times m$ points, you have

- $mn$ unknowns
- $2(m+n-1)$ values at the boundary.
- $2(m-2)(n-2)$ equations at the center

The total number of equations you have is

$$
2(m-2)(n-2) + 2(m+n-1) = 2mn -2m -2n +6
$$

As you have $mn$ values to find, this solution is over-determined for

$$
\left(2mn -2m -2n +6\right) - mn < 0
$$

$$
m(n-2)< 2n-6
$$
$$
m<2-\dfrac{2}{n-2} < 2
$$

So, if there's at least a solution to this problem, there are $(mn-2m-2n+6)$ equations that are linear-dependent on the others.

Your solution depends highly on the boundary conditions. It's different if you have only one equation (instead of two) because you can put whatever you want for $\alpha^{B}$ and you still solve the system.

**For example:** For a mesh $3 \times 3$, $8$ values are at BC and there's only $1$ unknown. But that means the $8$ values on the boundary must satisfy

$$
\alpha_{00} + \alpha_{20} + \alpha_{22} + \alpha_{02} = \alpha_{10} + \alpha_{01} + \alpha_{12} + \alpha_{21} 
$$

So, instead of $8$ values on the boundary, you can put only $7$ values and get the same solution.

For a mesh of $n \times m$ points, there are

- $nm$ unknowns
- $2(m+n-1)$ values at the boundary
- $2(n-2)(m-2)$ equations at the center.

In fact, the DOFs (Degrees of Freedom) on your BC is only

$$
mn - 2\left(m-2\right)(n-2) = -mn+4m+4n-8
$$

instead of $2(m+n-1)$. And if you have $m$ and $n$ very big, this value becomes negative and only one possibility is allowed:

$$
\alpha_{ij} = \text{const}
$$